# php ZipArchive - do I have this class if I have zip_open?

Tags: php, zip

Simple question really, but I'm just not sure about the answer:
if I have all the zip_* functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) available, does that mean I also have the ZipArchive class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) available? PHP 5.3+.

Comment: Since they belong to the same extension I don't think there's a way to disable the latter but not the former. Now, you don't need to ask in a forum whether you have a given class available. Just [see it by yourself](http://php.net/class_exists).

Comment: Yeah, I can't really do that on every client's server, I don't have that kind of access. But the software is using the zip_* functions, so I was just wondering if the ZipArchive class is available aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, requirements are same. They both use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) so if it's installed, you will not have a requirement problem.

Both uses same [installation page](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) and need same configure options. So if one works, other one will work too. You just need to make sure php compiled with `--enable-zip`.

You can check it with `php -m | grep zlib` from command line. And phpinfo or `php -i` will show you zlib and zip version similar to this:

```
zip

Zip => enabled 
Extension Version => $Id:abc21c7f1559e732dba6db94c69ecf638ae5fa3f $ 
Zip version => 1.11.0
Libzip version => 0.10.1


zlib

ZLib Support => enabled 
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib:// 
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate 
Compiled Version => 1.2.8 
Linked Version => 1.2.8
```